# Why is this gradle script giving me an error?

Tags: gradle, ant

```
ant.javac(destDir: project.'health.check.dir') {
    src(path: project.'src.dir')
    classpath (refid: 'classpath')}
```

Why is this gradle script prompting me an error? I am pretty sure I've written it correctly but I am getting errors that says "compile failed: see the compiler eror output for details"

Comment: Compilation is a result of a syntax error in your program or unmet dependencies in compiling your program. You need to show all the details of your error message to give some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The following `build.gradle` works:

```
task test << {
    ant.javac(
        destDir: project['health.check.dir'],
        srcDir:  project['src.dir']) {

        classpath refid: 'classpath'
    }
}
```

when you execute:

```
gradle test -Phealth.check.dir=/home/martin -Psrc.dir=hm
```

Comment: When I put that script in I get errors from my java files. About symbol cannot be found.

Comment: Well that would mean that the `classpath` or `srcdirs` are not correctly set. If javac compiler cannot found symbol it means it cannot find class that is used in class that it just tries to compile.